# css speech bubble responsive and hidden

Tags: javascript, css

I was reading [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/) article regarding how to make a simple css speech bubble.

How would you make the bubble adjust its size according to the text inside of it, and also hide when there's no text?

I'm fine with using js if necessary but it would be cool to do it just from the css.

html:

```
<p class="speech">SitePoint Rocks!</p>
```

css:

```
p.speech
{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 8px solid #666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
}
```

---

NOTE:

The CSS provided in the article that I have linked above was incompatible with my needs. I had to look for another responsive css speech bubble and I found this fantastic tool: http://www.ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/

Comment: @RohitKumar the code in the article is literally all the code that I am using

Comment: I was asking for the html code

Comment: the html code is in the article - just added it to the question

Answer (score 2):

The "css only" way to hide the bubble when there's no text:

```
p.speech:empty:before,
p.speech:empty:after{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: this works! and makes perfect sense. You just forgot to add the class p.speech:empty (without :before and :after). Any idea as to how I would go about the size responsiveness of the bubble?

Comment: @jgozal i posted a link regarding the size of the text

Answer (score 2):

Size and hide with jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".description > em").hide();
  $('a.to_links').click(
    function() {
      $(this).next("em").show('800');
      $(this).hide();
    });
  $('a.out_links').click(
    function() {
      $(this).parent("em").hide();
      $(this).parent().parent().find('a.to_links').show('600');
    });
});
```

```css
.description {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 whiteSmoke;
  border: 1px solid #DBE1E6;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px white;
  filter: dropshadow(color=#ffffff, offx=1, offy=1);
  border: 8px solid #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
}
.description:empty:before {
  display: none;
}
.description:empty:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">Speech bubble css
  <a class="to_links">read more</a>
  <em> and a little bit of jQuery – just to show more content or hide it.
         <a class="out_links">less</a>
       </em>
</div>
```

[Reference](http://www.sweet-web-design.com/wordpress/speech-bubble-powered-by-css/1520/)

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks very much. I'm just trying to understand what you did here before trying it out. What are the <a> tags for?

Comment: ahhh in case the content is too big?

Comment: interesting. let me check how it looks!

Comment: jsfiddle.net/9tktpxrs/5/

Comment: the responsiveness is working fantastically. There's just an issue. Take a look at the article in the original question. There's a little more css aside from the css in the question (somebody edited my question). The speech bubble has a triangular tail that connects the person and the message. This triangular tail (constructed with the classes p.speech:before and p:speech:after) is not adjusting its position and is for some reason dwelling within the bubble. What should I add to the other classes for the tail to remain in its place?

Comment: it looks like the previous issue is being caused by the overflow:hidden, but overflow:hidden is needed to wrap the text in the bubble

Comment: @jgozal i would suggest that you don't use their css, rather that you put an img of a tail in a div and show them side by side

Comment: you're right, I'm going to look for another bubble. Thank you for your help!